# SQL - Duplicates in join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, distinct

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table1 AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t
ON s.s_id = t.t_id
WHERE (
s.body LIKE  '%string%'
OR t.name LIKE  '%string%'
)
ORDER BY s.time DESC
```

but I am still getting duplicate tuples. Why is this?

Comment: I would never use `SELECT DISTINCT *`, especially with multiple tables. Be specific about what columns you want back

Comment: Might need to show us some of your data

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * will never identify rows as duplicated if even 1 value a slightly bit different. You dont have absolutely equal rows in result here.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY s.s_id
```

was the solution.

Comment: That will prevent duplicate IDs, but isn't necessary to prevent duplicate tuples -- DISTINCT ensures that the tuples are unique.

Comment: @Barmar: using DISTINCT as a go-to answer is not a good idea as DISTINCT after a JOIN usually means there's a poorly designed query or the data is poorly organized. That is, the DISTINCT is used to paper over a real problem, rather than to fix it.

Comment: @siride I'm not recommending DISTINCT, just saying that this answer is to a different question than the one he asked. He probably needs to clarify the question. He apparently wants a particular column to be unique, not the tuples.

Comment: @Barmar: actually, the question asked why duplicate tuples were showing up. The answer could be that the JOINs are wrong, or that the tables are wrong. DISTINCT is not the only required answer.

Comment: There were actually no duplicate tuples, i figured out. That's why distinct was not doing what I thought it should. It was a matter of duplicate columns, in this case s.s_id

Answer (score 0):

1. The result doesn't contain absolutely equal rows here so technically they aren't duplicated
2. To get rid of duplicates, you need to SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY only fields you need non-duplicated and outer join the rest data in subquery on the corresponding key values, taking only 1 (first or last or whatever) row from them.